# Highcharts -- exporting, setting dataLabel options

Tags: highcharts

I've using Highcharts 2.3.5.  In the "exporting' object, under "chartOptions", I'm able to change some things when exporting, like the background color of the chart, but I haven't been able to enable the dataLabels nor change the marker size.

Here's an example, of what works and doesn't work.  In this case, when exporting, I want to change the background color (which works) and make sure the data labels appear (which doesn't work) :
...

```
    exporting : {
        chartOptions : {
              chart: { backgroundColor: '#ff0000'}, //this works
              plotOptions: {
                    pie : {
                               dataLabels: {enabled: true}  //this one doesn't work
                            }
              }                         
}...
```

Am I missing something obvious?
j

Comment: Reported: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1562 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#container1').highcharts({
        exporting: {
            chartOptions: { // specific options for the exported image
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            scale: 3,
            fallbackToExportServer: false
        },
```